# Get response for send() in stomp.py to retry the in case of failure

Tags: python, activemq-artemis, stomp.py

Below is my listener class with the subscriber

```
import os
import time
import stomp

def connect_and_subscribe(conn):
    conn.connect('guest', 'guest', wait=True)
    conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/test', id=1, ack='auto')

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn

    def on_error(self, frame):
        print('received an error "%s"' % frame.body)

    def on_message(self, frame):
        print('received a message "%s"' % frame.body)
        for x in range(10):
            print(x)
            time.sleep(1)
        print('processed message')

    def on_disconnected(self):
        print('disconnected')
        connect_and_subscribe(self.conn)

conn = stomp.Connection([('localhost', 62613)], heartbeats=(4000, 4000))
conn.set_listener('', MyListener(conn))
connect_and_subscribe(conn)
time.sleep(60)
conn.disconnect()
```

Below is my producer code

```
import stomp
conn = stomp.Connection([('localhost', 62613)])
conn.connect('guest', 'guest', wait=True)
result = conn.send('/queue/test', 'test message')
```

I need to get the result/status of sent data, in order use that status to retry in case of failover

I know this details can be received in on_send listener

```
on_send SEND {'content-length': 5, 'destination': '/queue/test'} b'a test message'
```

But for this I need to create a class inheriting ConnectionListener class, and add method on_send Listener to get the response.

Is it possible to get the response without creating any class?

Thanks

Comment: What broker are you using?

Comment: I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis.
https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/

Comment: @JustinBertram do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: I don't have anything conclusive as the API documentation isn't very good. However, my suspicion is that the `send` method is synchronous so that if there was any problem it would be reported back to you directly without needing to create any kind of callback/listener.

Comment: Documentation you are referring to stomp.py docs?
Because I'm able to achieve this using php-stomp.

`$success = PhpStomp::send_message($topic, $content, $headers);`

`$status = $success ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL";`

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the [stomp.py documentation](http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/index.html). The behavior of the php-stomp client isn't really relevant as it's a completely different implementation.